# Pyenv cannot be installed in Manjaro Linux

Tags: python, make, manjaro, compiler

Hello I have been trying to install `pyenv` on Manjaro Linux and got an error that openssl is not installed on the system.  I have now installed it.

I understand that
I am supposed to tell the compiler where the packages are located with the strings
`LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/openssl-1.0"` and `CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl-1.0`. 
Where do I place these strings in order to ensure that `pyenv` is installed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: run:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/openssl-1.0" CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl-1.0" pyenv install -v version
```

in terminal and `pyenv` which would already be installed and desired pthon
version will be installed.